# Step in proving that graphs of smooth functions are embedded submanifolds

Tags: proof-explanation, smooth-manifolds

From Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*:

**Proposition 5.4 (Graphs as Submanifolds)**. Suppose $M$ is a smooth $m$-manifold (without boundary), $N$ is a smooth $n$-manifold with or without boundary, $U\subseteq  M$ is open, and $f:U\to N$ is a smooth map. Let $\Lambda(f)\subseteq M\times N$ denote the graph of $f$. Then $\Gamma(f)$ is an embedded $m$-dimensional submanifold of $M \times N$

*Proof.* Define a map $\gamma_f:U\to M\times N$ by
$$x\mapsto (x,f(x)).$$
It is a smooth map whose image is $\Gamma(f)$ Because the projection $\pi_M:M \times N \to M$ satisfies $\pi_M \circ \gamma_f(x)=x$ for $x\in U$, the composition $d(\pi_M)_{(x,f(x))}\circ d(\gamma_f)_x$ **is the identity on $T_xM$** for each $x\in U$...

---

Why does the statement in bold hold?

Answer (score 0):

Because $\pi_M \circ \gamma_f$ is the identity of $U$ and the differential preserves identity and behaves well with composition (in fact there is a functor from pointed manifolds to vector spaces) .
Remember that if $U$ is open in $M$ and $p\in U$, then $T_{p} U=T_{p} M$.